# Android MediaPlayer seekBar not working correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

Currently, I'm developing a media player and I need seekBar to work together, at the moment, it's everything okay! but, **when I touch at determinated position of the seekbar**, the mediaplayer *must follow* and set the song to this determinated position, but the song and seekBar **back to the start** and I don't know why it's happening.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public TextView song_detail;
    public TextView time1;
    public TextView time2;
    private String player_status = "playing";
    private ImageButton player_img;

    public static SeekBar seekBar;

    private static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        song_detail = findViewById(R.id.song_detail);
        song_detail.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        time1 = findViewById(R.id.time_1);
        time2 = findViewById(R.id.time_2);

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mediaPlayer != null){
                    int CurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    String m_1;
                    String s_1;
                    seekBar.setProgress(CurrentPosition/1000);
                    final int minutes_1 = (CurrentPosition/1000)/60;
                    final int seconds_1 = ((CurrentPosition/1000)%60);

                    if (minutes_1 < 10) {
                        m_1 = "0" + minutes_1;
                    } else {
                        m_1 = "" + minutes_1;
                    }

                    if (seconds_1 < 10) {
                        s_1 = "0" + seconds_1;
                    } else {
                        s_1 = "" + seconds_1;
                    }
                    time1.setText(m_1 + ":" + s_1);


                    int Duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    String m_2;
                    String s_2;
                    final int minutes_2 = (Duration/1000)/60;
                    final int seconds_2 = ((Duration/1000)%60);

                    if (minutes_2 < 10) {
                        m_2 = "0" + minutes_2;
                    } else {
                        m_2 = "" + minutes_2;
                    }

                    if (seconds_2 < 10) {
                        s_2 = "0" + seconds_2;
                    } else {
                        s_2 = "" + seconds_2;
                    }

                    time2.setText(m_2 + ":" + s_2);

                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        mRunnable.run();


        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(progress), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
        });
    }

    public void initAudio(final Context context, final String url) {
        if (mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(url));
        }
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                killMediaPlayer();
            }
        });
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void killMediaPlayer() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void pauseAudio() {
        if (!(mediaPlayer == null)) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
    public static void startAudio() {
        if (!(mediaPlayer == null)) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part of code that I'm using to work with *mediaPlayer* and *seekBar*

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(progress), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
        });
    }
```

But as I have said, instead of mediaPlayer seek and continue the audio from the position that I've clicked, the audio simply back to the start. What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max value for `progress` is 100. The `seekTo` function takes time in milliseconds. This is why it seeks to the start (almost) of the audio.

So instead of `mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);`, you need to do:

```
long newTime = (progress/100.0) * total_audio_duration_in_millisecond; 
mediaPlayer.seekTo(newTime);
```

Comment: not currentDuration(), the total duration : `mediaPlayer.getDuration()`

Comment: I'm getting: `error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to long` at `long newTime = (progress/100.0) * mediaPlayer.getDuration();`

Comment: `long newTime = (long) ((progress/100.0) * mediaPlayer.getDuration());`

Comment: `error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int`

Comment: have you declared newTime as int?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Just cast the long to int : `mediaPlayer.seekTo((int)newTime);`

Comment: It's not working correctly, I click at determinated position of seekBar, and the position set is different

Comment: any reason you have `seekBar.setProgress(progress);` in onProgressChanged?

Comment: remove that line

Comment: Done sir, but when I click at determinated position, the audio go to another

Comment: what do you mean " audio go to another"? Does it go to another audio?

Comment: Another position, if I click at 00:50, it goes to 02:38, for example.

Comment: How do you know you click at 00:50?

Comment: It was just a example. I'm trying to explain that is not correct

Comment: `seekBar.setProgress(CurrentPosition/1000);` this code is wrong

Comment: it should be

 `int progress=(int)((currentPosition/(float)totalDuration)*100);

seekBar.setProgress(progress);`

Comment: This part is correct too? `seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000);`

Comment: yes remove that.. let the max for seekBar be 100 (default)

Comment: My seekBar progress is not being updated, it's freezed at the start

Comment: Hey sir, I just solved the problem using this: `progress*1000`